# JarJar with Ant - how to use a Rule file

Tags: ant, jarjar

I would like to know how to run [JarJar](http://code.google.com/p/jarjar) with Ant, passing the rules in with an external Rules file.

---

1) I know I can pass the rules in one by one as below:

```
    <jarjar destfile="B.jar" >
        <zipfileset src="A.jar" />

        <rule pattern="com.a.**" result="test.b.@1" />
    </jarjar>
```

2) I know I can pass the rules in a file if I run it from the command line:

```
    java -jar jarjar.jar process <rulesFile> <inJar> <outJar>
```

3) I can use the above command line in an Ant `<exec>` task. (best workaround)

4) I found some reference to using a `<rulesFile>` tag in Maven.

---

The above options are not ideal for what I would like to do.

I want to run JarJar from an Ant task, passing in a rules file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been unable to get any information about this, from any forum, or by mailing the developers of JarJar, so I have decided to answer this question with a **workaround** that I am using:

- Use the DOCTYPE & ENTITY xml entities (as per [suggestion on Ant website](http://ant.apache.org/faq.html#xml-entity-include))

As an example, the below `build.xml` file includes the contents of another `test.txt` file inline. I import the text file using the tag `include_this` (this is my name - you can use any name here):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE project [
    <!ENTITY include_this SYSTEM "test.txt">
]>

<project name="Test" default="build" >

    <target name="build" >
        &include_this;
    </target>

</project>
```

In this simple example, the contents of the `test.txt` file is:

```
<echo>This is a test.</echo>
```

So I've been using this workaround to replace the rules in the `jarjar` call. Putting the rules in the `test.txt` file:

```
<rule pattern="com.**" result="${project.output}.com.@1" />
<rule pattern="org.**" result="${project.output}.org.@1" />
```

My `jarjar` call then becomes:

```
<!-- jarjar uses the same syntax as the jar task -->
<jarjar destfile="${jarjar.output.dir}/${project.output}.jar" >
    <!-- source files -->
    <zipfileset src="${jar.output.dir}/${project.output}.jar" />

    <!-- refactoring rules -->
    &include_this;
</jarjar>
```